# Buffer overflow in C (using GDB in Linux)

Tags: c, linux, gdb, overflow

I can't understand the sequence of actions

There is a program (the source code of which is given below,
compile with keys: -fno-stack-protector -no-pie). You need to analyze the program using a debugger to find out the length of the array for entering the password and the address of the branch of the password validation condition, which is performed if the passwords match. Enter the password (a string of characters) in such a way as to overwrite the return address to the clarified address (there are characters that cannot be entered from the keyboard, so you can use input redirection  when starting the program)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int IsPassOk(void);
int main(void)
{
 int PwStatus;
 puts("Enter password:");
 PwStatus = IsPassOk();
 if (PwStatus == 0) {
     printf("Bad password!\n");
     exit(1);
 } else {
 printf("Access granted!\n"); // the string to find out the address for
 }
return 0;
}

int IsPassOk(void)
{
 char Pass[12];
 gets(Pass);
 return 0 == strcmp(Pass, "test");
}
```

Comment: These kind of exercises are often pointless since they rely on a lot of implementation details. You are supposed to figure out the location of the return address from `IsPassOk` in relation to the buffer `Pass`. If it happens to be located further down on the stack than the buffer, then tough luck... Stacks in Linux are down-counting though (that's most common by far) so at least you know that much.

Comment: You are supposed to give a password of maximum 12 bytes. But since there is no check on the size of password, you are able to overflow ```Pass``` simply by providing more than 12 bytes. Since stack is growing downward, you start to destroy return address by which the ```Program Counter``` knows where to start execution after ```IsPassOK``` is finished. You can therefore, make a deliberate password to overwrite this ```returning address``` to somewhere else that you'd like to execute your desired shellcode.